# Are questions regarding making modifiers allowed?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if questions about making modifiers are allowed. I did a couple of searches here and there and many questions similar to what I was going to ask were closed. I did read a question about types of questions that should be off topic and closed (as quickly as possible) and it seems they are too.

But modifiers are specific to blender and only blender. They are not a programming language feature where you can just ask about them on a C++ forum. I understand python questions are allowed here since it's used in blender, so can't we allow a little bit of C++ code once in a while? It's really frustrating for me since I have tried for many months and asked practically everywhere about something as simple as a hello world modifier;  to this day I'm still as clueless as I was a year ago. I am really about to give up :(

Comment: that is easy to say, actually everytime i get that answer and i'm almost certain that person they never tried.. because it's very very difficult ,even changing one line of code of a modifier breaks blender and i have to undo changes.. i can swear the code is obfuscated for some reason.. any help is appreciated, if you could that is

Comment: many thanks for your time,i was able to get the same result as your example,had a little issue but managed to get it working after a few headaches,i now have enough to continue on my journey, thanks againt and sorry.u can delete,  i saved your post for future reference! cheers man , have a good night/day.

Comment: i also don't mind if this question get closed, sorry for being selfish this place was my last hope and i wasn't disappointed :D

Comment: If you're asking about a modifier, it seems to me that this is part of the source code, which would make this substantially a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/225/are-questions-about-modifying-the-source-code-allowed-here?rq=1). I don't know what your level of sophistication is with C++, or how much you know about the internals of the source code, but perhaps [this page](https://www.blender.org/get-involved/developers/) is a good place to start. Developing an add-on would be something  a  bit different, but  that, too, would seem to be out of scope

Comment: ohh my comments look like i'm talking to myself ,heh. brasshat yes i did know my question is similar i was wondering why they can't be allowed here , they aren't that vague and only deal with a small portion of blender's code. btw someone else helped me here the other day,and i did get some links to an actual example. who do i contact to mark this question as solved? or should i just delete it ?

Comment: While the Blenderartists forum uses the "[solved]" designator, BSE has typically not, though I suppose it could edited in in front of the question. I would suggest, though, that you not delete the question..

Comment: @brasshat [there is never a good reason to add "solved" to a question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/278094) That is something from and for forums, not a Q&A site like SE where we have other tools (like accepted answers).